# Configuration of the Office 365 "Encrypt" menu in Outlook 2016

Tags: office365, azure, microsoft-outlook-2016

We have configured AIP on our Office365. Labels and policies are configured, and the Protect ribbon has already shown in Outlook. However there is another set of options shown under the Encrypt menu which I suspect were created earlier. Please see attached picture:

[image: printscreen]

How can I remove these options under this encrypt menu in Outlook 2016?

Answer (score 0):

These are RMS template, individual message encryption options for end-users. Maybe you can check this article:https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/information-protection/configure-usage-rights#encrypt-only-option-for-emails